# Are unknown lenders safe to use?

Tags: mortgage, banking, lending

I want to refinance my mortgage, so I went searching for rates and a typical page on [BankRate](http://www.bankrate.com/mortgage.aspx) looks like this:

[image]

These rates are a good half a percent less than what's offered by the major banks, but I've never heard of any of these lenders and they might be unreliable or outright scams.

So how would I know if one of these banks is a company I dare do business with for something as critical as a mortgage?

Comment: Same way you research any other company you aren't sure you should trust...

Comment: @keshlam: well, yes, but what specifics do I need to worry about with a mortgage that is different with a different kind of product with much lower stakes?

Answer (score 6):

Most of these are either brokers and you're actually getting a mortgage from some other bank that doesn't want to invest in its own retail operations, or fronts for private investors, REIT funds, etc. In many cases, these companies issue a mortgage and immediately sell it to some other bank - profiting from the origination charges and points you paid them, and shifting the risk to someone else.

They are (probably...) legit, in most (if not all) States they must be licensed and regulated, but the devil is in the details: the rates may be low, but the fine print is such that you would probably never qualify to the low rate you see and end up either getting a higher rate, or paying points to get to the rate you want. Classic bait and switch.

But, in some cases, you may really end up with an awesome rate....

Comment: I'm not too worried about bait and switch, because I'll see that up front before signing anything. I'm more concerned about what kinds of issues I may run into after I'm locked into a 20 year relationship with these people.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank don't worry about it, in most cases it won't even be 20 weeks.

Comment: But what about horror stories where the bank does sleazy things and you can't get anyone on the phone to work it out, and that kind of thing?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank do your research, read he reviews